# kendoDatetimepicker error date.getTime is not a function

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to bind the datetime value to the kendo-datetimepicker control in angular and getting error  date.getTime is not a function. The date value doesn't show up in the control.

The examples I have seen so far shows using the new Date. But I am looping through a server object that contains the date and trying bind that date to the control. How do I do it

The date is in format 2019-06-23T23:00:00

Html

```
  <tr *ngFor="let c of FundClasses.FundClassColumnNames">
                    <th   [ngClass]="c != 'Buttons1'? 'tableItem bold' : 'tableItem cellbgcolor'"> {{ c }}</th>

                    <ng-container *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel let i=index">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
         <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Inception Date'"
                                        class="tableItem">
               <kendo-datepicker [format]="'MMM dd, yyyy'" [(ngModel)]="f.value.InceptionDate"  
                               class="form-control  form-control-sm">
                </kendo-datepicker>{{f.value.InceptionDate}}
        </td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
```

Comment: The error line would be helpful here

Comment: TypeError: date.getTime is not a function
    at cloneDate (clone-date.js:13)
    at DatePickerComponent.push../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs/dist/fesm5/index.js.DatePickerComponent.writeValue (index.js:4829)
    at forms.js:2118
    at forms.js:3273
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at

Answer (score 0):

Rather than [ngModel] you can use k-ng-model to bing date from model of yours.
you can  refer this link to see demo of such binding of model [CheckOverHere](http://dojo.telerik.com/oWah)

Comment: I have tried to use k-ng-model but it still is not binding however i dont see the getTime error. The value that i am getting the model is similar to the datestring value in the example. How so I return it as an object. I am not using jquery but Angular with Typescript. Also if you notice , my model value is retrieved using f.value.InceptionDate

Comment: @Tom can you share your console log

Comment: console.log of what

Comment: I meant do you want to see the value of f.value.InceptionDate

Comment: @console log of running application.. We are able to see console log after inspecting Element of  running application.Also can you show me value you are getting in f.value.InceptionDate ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using controlled datetimepicker make sure the value you pass into it is a Date object.
So yours `f.value.InceptionDate` should be `new Date("2019-06-23T23:00:00")` but not `"2019-06-23T23:00:00"`